# how to compare given data with database data one by one in java

Tags: java, mysql, netbeans, xampp

```
String name= uname.getText();
String password=new String (PassW.getPassword());
    
try {
    Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
    Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/attms?autoReconnect=true&useSSL=false","root","");
    
   Statement stm= con.createStatement();
   String q="SELECT * FROM admin;";                             

    ResultSet rs= stm.executeQuery(q);
   
    while (rs.next())
    {
        String user= rs.getString("Username");
        String pass= rs.getString("Password");
    
        if(name.equals(user)&& password.equals(pass)) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Welcome " +name ,"Login Successfull", JOptionPane.PLAIN_MESSAGE);
            new AdminFrame().setVisible(true);
            this.dispose();
        } else {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this,"Invalid Username&Password","",JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
             
        }  
    }
```

I want to compare given username with stored username data from database one by one and if the condition is true then allow to another frame
in this code i'm using if statement it's checking only one data

Answer (score 0):

Your `if-else` should be outside loop. Currently if first user does not match, you assume there is no match at all.

1. Have a boolean variable if match was found
2. In loop, check for match, if found set to true and break loop, otherwise continue looping
3. Check variable outside loop

Also it would be better if you get one user from database by username and then check password for match, there is no need to iterate through all users.